# How to call SOAP service from Azure Functions project?

Tags: azure, soap, azure-functions, soap-client, webservice-client

I created a new Azure Functions project with C#. I don't see any option to add a 'connected service' so I can generate a proxy for the SOAP API that I want to call. How do I do this with Azure Functions?

Comment: is it a WCF service?

Comment: @Sajeetharan it's JAX-WS, see https://api.bullhornstaffing.com/webservices-2.6/?wsdl

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to create a **Class Library** project and add the proxy (*Expand the project in the Solution Explorer > Right-click Dependencies > Add Connected Service*) to it. Then, add the Class Library reference to the Azure Function. In addition, it is also possible to add it directly to the Azure Function project.

The instructions above and the following screenshot were based on Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.7.2) Enterprise Edition.

[image]

Comment: Make sure if you have a class function that uses it, it does it in dotnet standard for functions V2, if you're using version 2 of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use **`HttpClient`**. Here is what the calling function could look like:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    var url = "https://<functionapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/Function2?code=<code>";
    var response = await client.GetAsync('https://api.bullhornstaffing.com/webservices-2.6/');
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Function 1 " + result);
}
```