# How to map json data to xml to call webservice from azure function c#

Tags: c#, json, xml, azure, azure-functions

I have below Azure Function c# code which works fine.

I call webservice and pass xml data as input but Azure function got json data.

How can I map this xml data and pass while calling webservice?

```
            string Jsonbody = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // I'm confused how to map this Jsonbody data to xml and pass to httpContent

            var httpContent = new StringContent(Jsonbody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");


            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            string requestUri = "https://mydemo.com/myservice.asmx?listdata";

            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent);

            string result = await new StreamReader(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result).ReadToEndAsync();
```

For example -
Function app input json -

```
{
  "Name": "00141169",
  "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
  "Date": "2020-04-03",
}
```

map to this xml which is input to webservice which will pass to `httpContent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <listdata xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Name>KH001</Name>
      <CurrencyCode>01/01/2018</CurrencyCode>
      <Date>01/01/2020</Date>
    </listdata>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Like in Json we use Json serialization using c# class and then assign values is there anything we can do with Xml?

I have many more fields above 3 fields are only sample data.

> If I directly call function app from postman and pass xml input into
>   body it works fine. my question is if function app input is json how
>   to map it into xml and pass.

Comment: You probably need to modify the request is specify you want xml response instead of json.

Comment: Typically when calling asmx services you will [create a service reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784226/how-to-call-soap-service-from-azure-functions-project). That reference will have classes that  you can map your json properties to and a proxy that you can call instead of using `HttpClient`.

Comment: if I pass it as xml from postman like modified question it works my question is if input is json how to map it to xml and pass it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know how to deserialize the XML from the JSON string, you could use the following code, in my test I won't call other Webservice I suppose the deserialization is the main problem.

You could use `JsonConvert` to do the deserialization and in my test I will return the XML directly.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(requestBody);

            return new ContentResult { Content = node.ToString(), ContentType = "application/xml" };
        }
```

[image]

Suppose after this you could call the Webservice request with this XML, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

**Update**: my understanding is you want to select some value or remove some value, if yes you could refer to my below code.

```
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(requestBody);

            XmlNode rootnode = doc.SelectSingleNode("listdata");

            XmlNode Datenode = rootnode.SelectSingleNode("Date");

            rootnode.RemoveChild(Datenode);


            return new ContentResult { Content = doc.InnerXml.ToString(), ContentType = "application/xml" };
```

I get the json data from request and return a XML data(remove the `Date` node).

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot but what about mapping i mean if i have 4 fields into json and want to map only 2 fields into xml then ?